# Performance monitoring in Windows Phone 7 (power and FPS)

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, frame-rate, power-management

I have 2 questions on performance monitoring in WP7:

1) Enabling the FPS counters is [easy](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/), but how do I read current FPS into a variable? Is this even possible in WP7?

2) Is there an API to read current battery level and/or current consumption in milliamperes?

Comment: Thats what I thought...but no. Thats actually why I posted this question here.

Answer (score 2):

[After my initial comment to question and posters reply, I decided to have a dig around myself...]

1) I cannot find any mention of reading FPS programmatically. If you haven't already seen, this might be of interest: [Windows Phone Performance Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

2) As of the 7.1 SDK, there is no API to access the battery state.